# Wider margings but only in a zone (authors)

Tags: margins

I am using the ACM stylesheet to produce a paper with five authors. This means that the area under the title where all author names are is quite crammed and all the affiliations are split over multiple lines.

Is there a way to tell LaTeX to use wider margins for that area?

As this publication will be electronic only, it makes sense to use a small part of those generous margins and avoid all those breaks in the affiliations of the authors.

```
\documentclass{acm_proc_article-sp}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\permission{Permission to make digital or hard copies of part or all of this
work for personal or classroom use is granted without fee provided that
copies are not made or distributed for profit or commercial
advantage and that copies bear this notice and the full citation on the
first page. Copyrights for third-party components of this work must
be honored. For all other uses, contact the Owner/Author.\\
\\
Copyright is held by the owner/author(s).}
\conferenceinfo{XXXX}{Location
\copyrightetc{ACM \the\acmcopyr}
\crdata{978-1-XXXX-XXXX-X/XX/XX. \\
http://dx.doi.org/10.1145/XXXXXXXX.XXXXXX }
}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\@dotsep}{10000}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\title{Very very long title that will occupy at least two lines, maybe
even more}

\numberofauthors{5}

\author{
% 1st. author
\alignauthor Foo Barbar\\
       \affaddr{Abcdefg Hilmno pqr stuvzyzabcd}\\
       \affaddr{Osiauusyafse~ao~Ousya}\\
       \affaddr{Universit\"at~zu~K\"oln}\\
       \affaddr{Oaao, Osiaugt}\\
       \email{kkkk.kkkkkkkkk@kkkkkkk.kk}
% 2nd. author
\alignauthor Foo K. Barbarbar\\
       \affaddr{Aaaaaaaa bbb Ccccccccc Dddddddddd}\\
       \affaddr{Kkkkkkkkkk~aaa~Iiiiiiiii~Ffffff}\\
       \affaddr{Ofoaiisy, Jhahahe}\\
       \email{xxxxxxx.xxx@xxxxxxx.xx}
% 3rd. author
\alignauthor Foo Bar Bar\\
       \affaddr{Eeeeeeeee ff Gggggggg Hhhhhhh}\\
       \affaddr{Pppppppp aa Uuuuuuu}\\
       \affaddr{Oaoooaif, Slkei}\\
       \email{yyyyyyy@yyyyyyyy.yy}
\and
% 4th. author
\alignauthor Foo Barbar\\
       \affaddr{Iiiiiiiii lll Mmmmmmmm Nnnnnnnn}\\
       \affaddr{Wjjjjjjjj iue Jeeefffff Ttttttttt}\\
       \affaddr{Gooiaisy, Oiasytt}\\
       \email{yyyyyyyyyyy@yyyy.yyy}
% 5th. author
\alignauthor Foofoo Barbar\\
    \affaddr{Oooooooo pp Qqqqqq}\\
    \affaddr{Eqweoqeiro asad Oskskskka-Ugswlektn}\\
    \affaddr{Osoiausy, IISO}\\
    \email{yyyyyy@yyyy.yy}
}


\maketitle


\section{Preface}

\lipsum

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please provide a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv)

Comment: but what if someone tries to read the electronic-only article on a smartphone?  the author block will either be reflowed anyway, or the reader will have to do some serious scrolling -- a possibility which isn't always available on all devices, in which case information will be lost to the reader.  (i've seen this happen with badly designed e-pages, so it's not just hypothetical.)

Comment: This LaTeX file will produce a immutable PDF. That poor smartphone user will have to scroll around quite a bit. I would not suggest reading academical papers in PDF format with smartphones. :)